# What is the break-even point for a movie-theatre membership?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Your membership at the movie theatre is $75\;$ dollars plus $2\;$ for every movie. If you don't get a membership it is $5.75\;$. What number does $75\;$ and $5.75\;$ meet? And what is both of their equations..?

I have been stuck on this problem for 2 days !!! Somebody please help

Comment: What does "what number does 75 and 5.75 ""meet"" means??

Comment: Are you asking for what number of movie tickets is the amount paid by members equal to the amount paid by non-members?

Comment: I think this might be asking when does the cost of going to $x$ movies without a membership equal either the cost of the membership alone, or the cost of the membership and attending $x$ movies (not sure which of these).

Comment: Some people here are gifted with the power of guessing other people's intentions....wizards!

Answer (score 2):

Cost of attending $x$ movies in two months with membership = $75 + 2x$

Cost of attending $x$ movies in two months without membership = $5.75x$

The costs for attending $x$ movies are equal when $75 + 2x = 5.75x \iff 75 = 3.75 x$.

Can you solve for $x$ to determine how many movies one can watch in two months where the cost of either option: with or without membership, is equal - "break even"? $$x = \dfrac {75}{3.75} = 20$$

What value of $x$ makes membership worthwhile (cost less) than not being a member?

$$x > 20$$

Comment: In other words, if you are *not* a movie-theater addict, or prefer to rent rather than spend all the money at a theater, then unless you plan to *date* often and attend more than 20 movies in 2 months, *don't waste money on a membership*!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you attend $n$ movies.

If you don't get a membership, the total cost will be $75+2n$.  If you do get a membership, the total cost will be $5.75n$.  Setting them equal we get $75+2n=5.75n$, or $75=3.75n$.  We may divide by $3.75$ to get $n=20$ as the breakeven point between the two methods.